# Compare each row within each group

Tags: r

Following dataset is reproducible

```
group <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
parameter <- c("A","B","A","B","A","B")
values <- c(10,20,20,5,30,50)
df <- data.frame(group,parameter,values)

group parameter values
    1         A     10
    1         B     20
    2         A     20
    2         B      5
    3         A     30
    3         B     50
```

I want to check within each group whether A > B (store this result in fourth column for entire group)

If yes -> TRUE, If no -> FALSE

New Df:

```
group parameter values  status
    1         A     10      FALSE
    1         B     20      FALSE
    2         A     20      TRUE
    2         B      5      TRUE
    3         A     30      FALSE
    3         B     50      FALSE
```

Approach

with(df, ave(values,group, FUN = function(x)  ))

I am not able to think what will be the code inside the function. Can someone please help me

Updated: Status should be ranked as per the values column (highest to lowest) per group

```
group parameter values  status
    1         A     10      2
    1         B     20      1
    2         A     20      1
    2         B      5      2
    3         A     30      2
    3         B     50      1
```

Comment: Are there always exactly 1 A and 1 B value in each group?

Comment: Yes exactly 1 A and 1 B value in each group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'group', compare the 'values' where 'parameter' is 'A' with that of 'B' and assign (`:=`) to create 'status'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, status := values[parameter=="A"]>values[parameter=="B"], by = group]
df
#   group parameter values status
#1:     1         A     10  FALSE
#2:     1         B     20  FALSE
#3:     2         A     20   TRUE
#4:     2         B      5   TRUE
#5:     3         A     30  FALSE
#6:     3         B     50  FALSE
```

and for the `rank`, use `frank` on the 'values' after grouping by 'group.

```
setDT(df)[, status:= frank(-values), group]
df
#   group parameter values status
#1:     1         A     10      2
#2:     1         B     20      1
#3:     2         A     20      1
#4:     2         B      5      2
#5:     3         A     30      2
#6:     3         B     50      1
```

---

Or with `ave`, we can compare the first value with second one (assuming that 'parameter' is ordered and also only two elements per 'group'

```
df$status <- with(df, as.logical(ave(values, group, FUN = function(x) x[1] > x[2])))
```

---

Or another option is to `order` the dataset by the first columns (in case it is not ordered), the subset the 'values' by the recycling of logical index, compare and replicate each of the logical values by 2.

```
df1 <- df[do.call(order, df[1:2]), ]
rep(df1$values[c(TRUE, FALSE)] > df1$values[c(FALSE, TRUE)], each = 2)
```

Comment: Hey, that is cool. Suppose if I want to rank the parameter, is the solution on the same lines?

Comment: @Hardik Can you update your post with the expected rank

Answer (score 2):

There is also the `tidyverse` solution using `dplyr`:

```
    library(dplyr)

    df %>% 
      group_by(group) %>% 
      mutate(status = ifelse(values[parameter == "A"] > values[parameter == "B"], TRUE, FALSE),
             rank = min_rank(-values))

Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: group [3]

  group parameter values status  rank
  (dbl)    (fctr)  (dbl)  (lgl) (int)
1     1         A     10  FALSE     2
2     1         B     20  FALSE     1
3     2         A     20   TRUE     1
4     2         B      5   TRUE     2
5     3         A     30  FALSE     2
6     3         B     50  FALSE     1
```